Arrange photos in Pictures app by date taken
I moved a large volume of photo files from my Samsung Galaxy S10 (running Android 11) to my computer for backup, but then copied them back, realizing that I still wanted them on the phone. Now some of them are listed in the Pictures app as taken on the day I re-added them. How can I get them sorted under the proper dates?

Does this answer your question? How can I transfer photos to my Android Jelly Bean device while preserving the original timestamp?

There is an app that claims to restore file dates from exif date: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.duong.imagedatefixer
